# "Color" property error in SvgPicture in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, colors

I'm coding a web app in Flutter and I have a problem with the "color" property of SvgPicture. In the last line I make a color change in the icon depending on whether the menu button is selected or not, if I see the web on the computer it changes color correctly, but on a mobile device it doesn't change the color.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 55,
        height: 55,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
          color: widget.isSelected ? MyColors.yellow : MyColors.background3),
        child: MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
              onTap: () {
                widget.page();
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, top: 10.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(widget.icon, color: widget.isSelected ? MyColors.background3 : MyColors.grey),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `StatefulWidget` and `setState` when changing the color? If it is a `StatelessWidget`, referring to `widget.isSelected` will not result in a rebuild.

Comment: I don't know if it's still the case, but when I tried some time ago, the "color" argument was ignored in flutter-web with the html renderer. In that case, you might have better results with the ColorFiltered widget. Also, are you sure you're using the newest version of flutter_svg? The "color" argument is now deprecated, replated with "colorFilter".

Comment: @TomaszNoinski I have checked the version of flutter_svg and it was 0.22.0 and we are at 2.0.7, so you were right and it already works for me with colorFilter. I don't know why that version was added, thank you very much.